# How to access server controls for eg. Textbox values in aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Can I access server control values in aspx design page. 
For now being its just my curiosity but may be in need on tomorrow or so. 
For example I have a label in aspx page and I want to assign a textbox value to it.

I know I can use aspx.cs file instead but any desired suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance......   :)

Comment: Use Java Script for client side calculations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways.

1) var txtbox = Document.getElementbyId("<%= texboxId.ClientID%>"); txtbox.value = "new";

2) var txtbox = $("#" + "<%= texboxId.ClientID%>"); txtbox.value = "new";

3) var txtbox = $get("texboxId"); txtbox.value = "new";

If you are using Asp.Net 4.0 then the easy way is

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtboxId" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

and access it directly without using ClientID.

1) var txtbox = Document.getElementbyId("txtboxId"); txtbox.value = "new";

2) var txtbox = $("#txtboxId"); txtbox.value = "new";

For number 2 you need Jquery and for number 3 you need Microsoft AJAX library.

Comment: Thanks @Kamran Pervaiz  don't know about software development but you have signs of a good teacher........  take care :)

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text="Ajendra" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>` `<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%#this.TextBox1.Text;%>"></asp:Label>`  Am I doing right ? getting error ")" missing. javascript is doing fine :)

Comment: what do you want to achieve? your code will just make the label text as textbox text. which you can do it in codebehind. Label2.Text = TextBox1.Text;

Comment: I want to assign the text of TextBox1 to Label2's text property using the same technique in a right way. I mean like I can concatenate the entered text to the text property of a link button to move to te new page with that entered parameter.

Comment: I know using code behind its very easy but I think how it will be done if I want to do it in design pade

Comment: so let me rephrase your comment. you want to change the label text on a link button click and the text should be from textbox? Am i correct?

Comment: no friend that was just a example. ok have a look at this  :  `<a href="../abc.aspx?(text from textbox1)">Print</a>`

Comment: and the text for textbox is entered during runtime. I hope you got me now  :)

Comment: Now solution to your problem could be...hook a javascript function on onchange event of textbox like func(this)...and in that javascript function get the <a> and change its href according to your need. hope it helps

Comment: small example. <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox" onchange="change(this)"/>
        <a href="AccidentEmail.htm" id="link">click me</a> <script type="text/javascript">
        function change(txtbox) {
            var a = document.getElementById("link");
            a.href += "?" + txtbox.value;
        }
    </script>

Comment: Hi @Kamran Pervaiz `<script type="text/javascript">
    function change(txtbox) { var a = document.getElementById("link");a.href += "?Emp_Name=";  a.href+= txtbox.VALUE; } </script>` `<asp:TextBox ID="txtbox" runat="server" onchange="change(this)"></asp:TextBox> <a href="my_Page.aspx" id="link">click me</a>` . In my_Page.aspx I used the condition which is true but Emp_Name is showing "undefined"  :(. code in my_Page.aspx.cs is `string Emp = ""; if (Request.QueryString["Emp_Name"] != null)
            {
                Emp = Request.QueryString["Emp_Name"].ToString().Trim();
            }`

Comment: Check does it appear on URL in address bar or not. If not then debug javascript with alerts, If address is coming then there might be space in the Query string...

Comment: Hi @Kamran I checked and found I am not getting the textbox content in the url. Can u send me any working example at my email id : ajay_prasad09@yahoo.co.in